# How to change parent category color and child category color in product category widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

how to highlight the category of the selected parent category without highlighting the child categorys? i tried many stuff and not able to solve it.

My css now looks like :

```
    .widget .children .current-cat {
        background-color: beige;
    }
```

PS: HTML WooCommerce Widget:

```html
<div id="woocommerce_product_categories-2" class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories" style="padding: 15px;border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: rgba(9,12,15,0.28);">
<ul class="product-categories">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-39 cat-parent current-cat-parent"><a href="https://">Videoüberwachung</a>
<ul class="children">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-43 current-cat"><a href=/">HDCVI Kameras</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-44"><a href="/">IP-Netzwerk Kameras</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code!

Comment: sorry... done it

Answer (score 0):

.sidebar-widget .product-categories .cat-item a{color: red;}
.sidebar-widget .product-categories .cat-item .children a{color: yellow;}

Comment: put it in `` block and correct `indentation`.

Comment: this not work for me